# Read the first line of the email message and forward with attachment - java.mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment, forwarding

I have a requirement where I need to process the first line in the email message and, possibly, forward it.

But the problem happens when this message has attachments. And I need to forward them as well. I just can't find a good example of processing email messages with java.mail in a safe way that would cater for multiple message structures. Also, the forwarding example is a problem.

Can anyone point me to a good resource with some code examples?
Thank you

The code of getting the first line of the email message, forwarding I don't have working:

```
private String getMessgaeFirstLine(Message msg) throws IOException, MessagingException{
    String result = null;
    Object objRef = msg.getContent();   
    Multipart mp = (Multipart) objRef;
    int count = mp.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart( i );
            if (bp instanceof MimeBodyPart )
                {
                MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) bp;

                if ( mbp.isMimeType( "text/plain" )) {
                result = (String) mbp.getContent();
                result = result.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
                break;
                } 
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code that you have done so far?

Comment: Hi Shreyos, thanks for the comment, the code is spread out over 2 classes and multiple methods... it would be a mess posting it here. I feel.

Comment: No need to post whole code, just the main portion that we need to look into, so that we can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be to forward the original message as an attachment to the new message.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#forward).